# Transferring a custom add-on to another Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-add-on

I created an [add-on for a Google Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on):

[image]

After saving it, I can see it in the add-on list:

[image]

How can I use this add-on in another Google Form?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Tools -> Script editor, copy the code and paste it inside the Script editor of your other form.

Comment: Thanks yeah that's a bit manual. My add on has around 10 files, it's a pain to copy to several other forms :(

Answer (score 0):

If your script isn't published as an add-on then you have to add it "manually" to each form. The alternative to avoid this is to publish the add-on.

An alternative is use your current project as a Library, but you should create a project bounded to each form and map the functions called from the menus and perhaps other functions too.

The mapping is done by writing functions on the bound projects as follow:

```
function myDialog(){
  return myLib.myDiaglog();
}
```